# How to append to a VARCHAR which is already full

Tags: mysql, sql, append, substring

I'm appending to a VARCHAR(255) field like this:

```
UPDATE tabale SET field=CONCAT(field, 'appendedValue') WHERE id=2
```

My Problem is that after some time, the field is full. Now I will get an overflow and the update does not work.

```
UPDATE tabale SET field=SUBSTR(CONCAT(field, 'appendedValue'), 255) WHERE id=2
```

I've tried to use a SUBSTR function, but I don't know the position where I need to substring.

**How can I do an append with substring keeping the tail of the string with a length of 255?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [RIGHT() functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_right)

```
UPDATE tabale SET field= RIGHT(CONCAT(field, 'appendedValue'), 255) WHERE id=2
```